Website made using Typescript and React is working on localhost but getting a MIME type error when deploying on a server using Filezilla
I have made a website which is running perfectly on localhost but when I uploaded it on the hosting platform freehosting using Filezilla, I am getting the error:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I am using the website freehosting.com to host my domain server. I uploaded the contents in public_html folder of the directory using Filezilla. As the website is not running and showing an error, freehosting.com doesn't show any logs.
I have created a .htaccess file and put
<IfModule
    text/javascript js tsx
/IfModule>
but it is still not working. The content-type in the response header shows text/HTML.
The network tab shows 2 tabs
xxxx.com- Response contains index.html file
main.tsx- Response contains main.tsx file
I have included all details to the best of my knowledge which is required to answer the question. There are no debugging logs as I am only getting this error. And nothing else is shown.
My index.html file is
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/assets/images/logo.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>xxxx</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Edit: The hosting service only allowed PHP and HTML type websites. That is why it was not working.

"I have made a website which is running perfectly on localhost" being served by...what? Some React dev server? "I uploaded the contents in public_html folder of the directory using Filezilla" did you build the project first? What webserver is your hosting service using? Why do you have an HTML script tag pointed at a Typescript React file it can't read or know what to do with?

Thanks a lot for your comment. I got to know that the hosting service only allows PHP or HTML based website and it was not working because of that. I am new at all this and was trying to check webserver of my hosting service when I found this.

As long as your React app is entirely statically generated (e.g. gatsby, nextjs SSG) or entirely client side (no SSR) you should be able to host it just about anywhere. But you'll have to build it, not just run the React dev server.

I executed the command "npm run build". Is that what you mean by building it? I also used vite if that helps.

Yes, that's what I mean by building it, but you have your script tag pointed at your unbuilt uncompiled Typescript TSX file. I'm sorry, but (and I mean no offense, we all started where you are) building on Typescript and React seems to be over your head right now. You're going to have to learn how the web actually works before you play around with TS and React: everything you come into contact with (documentation, hosting services, etc) is going to assume you already know stuff you seem to not know. Go basic first.

React and Typescript (and Vite for that matter) are not beginner-friendly, and they aren't built for that: they are tools to help professional devs ship better stuff, not help beginners ship their first forays into webdev. I'm not trying to gatekeep, you should definitely learn this stuff you just need more of a foundation in the basics and/or a solid mentor who can help you past the sharp corners.
